# Get default values from inherited classes in function with base class as argument in C++

Tags: c++

I have a code where I define a base class called Particle, and two inherited classes called Electron and Proton. The base and inherited classes have functions with same names that return some values (reason why I add the base class' functions as virtual). After that, I create another class called Source that takes the class Particle as input. In main I try to access the particle's data through the Source class, but it points to the base class Particle with empty values.

My goal is to be able to have a single function that takes the Source class as argument, and uses the default values of the inherited Particle classes when they are called in main. I've read somethings about using pointers, but am quite confused as this stage.

Here is an executable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Particle{

protected:
    std::string name;
    double mass;
    double charge;
    double energy;
    double sigma;

public:
    virtual std::string getName() {return name;};
    virtual double getCharge() {return charge;};
    virtual double getMass() {return mass;};
};

class Electron : public Particle{

private:
    std::string name = "e-";
    double mass = 9.1093837e-31;
    double charge = -1.60217663e-19;

public:
    std::string getName() override {return name;};
    double getMass() override {return mass;};
    double getCharge() override {return charge;};
};

class Proton : public Particle{

private:
    std::string name = "p+";
    double mass = 1.67262192e-27;
    double charge = +1.60217663e-19;

public:
    std::string getName() override {return name;};
    double getMass() override {return mass;};
    double getCharge() override {return charge;};
};

class Source{
private:
    Particle particle;
    int noPrimaries;
public:
    Particle getParticle() {return particle;};
    int getNoPrimaries() {return noPrimaries;};
    void setParticle(Particle p) {particle=p;};
    void setNoPrimaries(int n) {noPrimaries=n;};
};

void getSourceData(Source source){

    printf("Particle name   = %s\n", source.getParticle().getName().c_str());
    printf("Particle mass   = %e\n", source.getParticle().getMass());
    printf("Particle charge = %e\n", source.getParticle().getCharge());
    printf("Number of primaries = %i\n", source.getNoPrimaries());
}

int main(){

    Proton proton;
    Electron electron;

    Source source;
    source.setParticle(proton);
    source.setNoPrimaries(12);

    getSourceData(source);
}
```

I'd really appreciate if I could get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change the parameter of `getParticleData` to be of a reference type. That is, change `void getParticleData(Particle particle)` to `void getParticleData(const Particle &particle)`

Comment: `getParticleData()` should accepts its argument by reference  (i.e.  `Particle &particle`).   As is, you are passing by value, which slices the object data and also does not resolve calls of virtual functions to their most-derived versions.    Additionally, look up `const` - you have member functions that don't change state of objects.

Comment: Thank you @user12002570, I needed to update the question where there is another class called Source in the context. I tried adding your input, but I'm still confused there. I'd be so grateful if you could point me out the correction in the new edit?

Comment: There is a lot of misuse of inheritance going on here. Use either virtual methods or base class member variables for each quantity, having both is redundant. Your `Electron` and `Proton` classes already contain all the base class members of `Particle`, so now you have _multiple_ fields called `name`, `mass`, and `charge`. Storing and passing `Particle` by value in `Source` leads to object slicing, which is not what you want.

Comment: It looks like you can achieve everything you want without inheritance. Just a basic class and some helper methods or constants will do, no need for separate types and inheritance and polymorphic dispatch: `struct Particle { std::string name; double charge; }; /* ... */ Particle electron() { return Particle { "e-", -1.60217663e-19 }; } /* ... */ Particle proton() { return Particle { "p+", 1.60217663e-19 }; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a C++ example showing pure virtual baseclasses, inheritance and use of constructors as well as some more useful C++ patterns.

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Do not do this : 
// using namespace std;
// C++ Weekly - Ep 305 - Stop Using `using namespace`
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8

// C.128: Virtual functions should specify exactly one of virtual, override, or final
// https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-override

// When dealing with polymorphic classes always
// start with an interface (pure abstract baseclass)

class particle_itf
{
public: 
    // getters should never change state (thus const) 
    // and always succeed (noexcept)
    virtual const std::string& getName() const noexcept = 0; // avoid copying string data upon return
    virtual double getCharge() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual double getMass() const noexcept = 0;
};

// reuable implementation of the interface
// can be mixed in with other classes
class particle_impl : 
    public particle_itf
{
public:
    particle_impl(std::string_view name, double charge, double mass) :
        m_name{name},
        m_charge{charge},
        m_mass{mass}
    {
    }

    // use override here
    const std::string& getName() const noexcept override
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    double getCharge() const noexcept override
    {
        return m_charge;
    }

    double getMass() const noexcept override
    {
        return m_mass;
    }

protected:
    std::string m_name;
    double m_charge;
    double m_mass;
};

class electron_t :
    public particle_impl
{
public: 
    // now setting the correct data is just a matter
    // of passing the right values to the baseclass
    electron_t() :
        particle_impl{"Electron (e-)", 9.1093837e-31, -1.60217663e-19}
    {
    }
};

class proton_t :
    public particle_impl
{
public: 
    proton_t() :
        particle_impl{"Proton (p+)", .67262192e-27, +1.60217663e-19}
    {
    }
};

// instead of printf use C++ stream support
// this allows you to output to any stream (including files)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const particle_itf& particle)
{
    os << "Name = " << particle.getName() 
       << ", mass = " << particle.getMass() 
       << ", charge = " << particle.getCharge();
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    // When using polymorphic classes we need pointers to the baseclass
    // however in current C++ you should (almost never) have to use new/delete
    // use std::make_unique. This will avoid memory leaks.
    std::unique_ptr<particle_itf> electron = std::make_unique<electron_t>();
    std::unique_ptr<particle_itf> proton = std::make_unique<proton_t>();

    // you could also build a collection of particles using
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<particle_itf>> particles;
    particles.push_back(std::move(electron));
    particles.push_back(std::move(proton));
    
    for(const auto& particle_ptr : particles)
    {
        std::cout << *particle_ptr << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```